# Share value between itemupdating and itemupdated events

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

I have a list which has 30 odd columns.

I have attached two event handler to the list.
1. ItemUpdating
2. ItemUpdated

In ItemUpdating event, I am checking one field value for a change.

In ItemUpdating event, I want to do the processing, if value changes. I cann't do comparision here because before properties does not provide old values in the list item.

The processing includes few jobs and sending e-mails after completion.

I am looking for a solution where I can set the bit when field value changes in ItemUpdating. Check this bit if set do the processing in ItemUpdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to share values directly, you will have to use a secondary method to persist your data.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the **[property bag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.properties.aspx)** of the list item.

```
//the list item you want to update (typically SPItemEventProperties.ListItem in an event receiver
SPListItem specialItem = list.Items[0];
specialItem.Properties["some_persisted_key"] = "Some Value here";
specialItem.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Be sure to use `SystemUpdate` otherwise you run into the danger of [creating an endless loop](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/brandon-atkinson/update-sharepoint-list-item-itemupdated-event-without-endless-loop) (or disable event firing beforehand as described in that article).

In your `ItemUpdated` event you can access your value then simply by going for `specialItem.Properties["some_persisted_key"]`.

Comment: Where would you declare the specialItem? If you do it in ItemUpdating, it wouldn't be available in ItemUpdated so you would be stuck with the same issue. If you try to do it before both events, you would have your properties yet to access the list items. Are you saying to create a field in the list and use that for temp storage between events? Can it be done only in the event receiver code?

Comment: Have you tried it @calorie712? It's not about declaring `specialItem` it's about **setting a property** on the current list item. ItemUpdating is synchronous while ItemUpdated can be set to asynch or synchronous, hence you could write something into the list item properties in ItemUpdating (do a SystemUpdate) and later get that item properties again.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies things for me. I thought everything happened in the code and you were just kind of creating a temporary item and assigning it a temporary property value so you could use it across events. I understand you need to add a field to your list and you utilize it for storage of data that is usable across events.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. Every `SPListItem` has Properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.properties.aspx (Hashtable). This is not about fields of any kind, it is simply a property bag attached to the list item (`SPWeb` also have this property bag or `SPFarm`). This property bag is perfect for storing "system" or temporary stuff, you will never want your users to see. Yes you could create a field for that, but the OP asked about sharing a value between code fragments, no need for a field there. A property is enough with a key only you know.

Comment: Are there any considerations for multiple people updating list items and using list.item[0] in the code or disposal of the property bag?

Comment: The property bag is not disposed. Multiple people updating is the same considerations as for any list item being updated: the first one wins. As we're talking about `ItemUpdating` here, you could even work with multiple people as you could influence the outcome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45205/discussion-between-calorie712-and-moontear)

Comment: Does this work in MOSS 2007? I tried it without issuing a `specialItem.SystemUpdate(false)` because I saw another answer that said the item is going to get saved anyway. But then that didn't work because I realized `itemUpdating` has not yet saved the change. Then I used the `SystemUpdate(false)` but `itemUpdating` is being fired again, which is contrary to its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is the full solution that worked for me... Thanks so much to @moontear!

It allows me to use the current items property bag and nullifies the key each time so it doesn't retain the value.

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{    
    SPListItem currentItem = properties.List.Items.GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID);

    //I had to null out the key or I would have conflicts the next time the event is triggered
    currentItem.Properties["DateChanged"] = null;
    currentItem.SystemUpdate(false);

    currentItem.Properties["DateChanged"] = true;
    currentItem.SystemUpdate(false);
}

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToBoolean(currentItem.Properties["DateChanged"]))
        {
            //do something
        }
}
```

Comment: Great! Note that the properties only store string values, so it should be "true" or 1 instead of `true`. I guess it is automatically converted to something "stringy", so just a note.

Comment: Instead of creating "currentItem" (and doing a "GetItemById" lookup/Query), why didn't you just use "properties.ListItem"?  I just want to make sure this was an oversight and I am not missing something. :)

Comment: You can also leave off the "SystemUpdate()" call, since the item is already being saved when this handler is done.

Answer (score 0):

Create one column in the Main List, where values are changes say "OLDVALUES". Set that field using the `properties.ListItem["OLDVALUES"]=Value1+";" +Value2+";" +Value3+";";` in `ItemUpdating` event (take Value1, Values2 and Value3 using the  `properties.ListItem["Value1"]` and so on).

Now in Item Updating, use like

```
string oldValue = properties.ListItem["OLDVALUES"].ToString();
```

and slip in array and then you can set global variables and access them in your code. Remember its a SandBox solution approach for event receivers, not for farm solution.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Item version (optionally max to 2 or 5)

and on ItemUpdated use:

```
object oldValue = properties.ListItem.Versions[1]["FieldName"];
object currentValue = properties.ListItem.Versions[0]["FieldName"];
```

The versions index 0 will always return the current item version.(this happened for my test with about 5 modifications, I recommend test it again :) )